# How can I get pagination to work with filter using ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am allowing users to filter data from a select list of dropdowns and a slider. I have the filtering part working and displaying the data properly, the issue is when I try to paginate the data. I am using AJAX to pass the data from the form to the PHP filter script. Is it possible to store these values in $_SESSIONs and then pass those values back to the filter to display the proper values on the following pages?

Here is some of the code I am currently using

**index.php** - 
I am using the **custom-select** class to get the values of each form select value and send them to the jquery filterData function

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding:5px;color:#333;">
  <label for="citySelect">LOCATION</label>
  <select class="form-control custom-select citySelect" id="citySelect" data-id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    <optgroup label="France">
        <option disabled selected>Select A City</option>
        <option value="paris">Paris</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="keyWordSearch">KEYWORDS</label>
        <div class="iconContainer">
            <input type="text" class="form-control keyWordSearchStyle custom-select" name="keyWordSearch" id="keyWordSearch" placeholder="keyword search...">
            <i class="fa fa-search iconPosition"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The .onchange event on the index.php page sends the form data to the jquery function

```
$(".custom-select").on("change", function(){
    var city = $(".citySelect").val();      
    var page = 1;

    $("#refiningSearch").show();        
    filterOptionSelect(city, page);
});
```

Then in the jquery function **filterOptionSelect()** I send those values to the filterData.php page

```
function filterOptionSelect(city, page){
event.preventDefault();

var city = city;
var rate = $(".rateSelect").val();
var lowRange = $(".min").val();
var highRange = $(".max").val();
var keyword = $("#keyWordSearch").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "filterData.php",
    data: {
        "city": city,
        "rate": rate,
        "lowRange": lowRange,
        "highRange": highRange,
        "keyword": keyword,
    },
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.screenLoader').show();
    },
    success: function(response){
        var response = $.trim(response);
        if(response){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.screenLoader').fadeOut(500);
                $("#displayPage").html(response).fadeIn(2500);
            }, 800);                
          }
      }
  });
  $('.screenLoader').fadeOut(500);
 }
```

Finally in the **filterData.php** page,  I grab all of the variables and query them. The issue is when I try to paginate the data, I'm not quite sure how to go about updating the query with the new filter options. How would I go about using $_SESSIONS and returning those values back to **filterData.php** to update the query?

filterData.php

Here is the file I am using to filter the data. So far seems to work fine except for my pagination. It just returns values on the next page just like if I didn't use any filters.

```
$city = '';
$rate = '';
$lowAge = '';
$highAge = '';
$keyword = '';

$records_per_page = 6;
$starting_position = 0; 

if(isset($_POST["page"])){
     $starting_position = ($_POST["page"]-1) * $records_per_page;
}else{
    $starting_position = 1;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['city'])){
    $city = $filter->filter($_SESSION['city']); 
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['city'])){
        $city = $filter->filter($_POST['city']);
        $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['rate'])){
    $rate = $filter->filter($_SESSION['rate']);
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
        $rate = $filter->filter($_POST['rate']);
        $_SESSION['rate'] = $rate;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['lowRange'])){
    $lowAge = $filter->filter($_SESSION['lowRange']);
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['lowRange'])){
        $lowAge = $filter->filter($_POST['lowRange']);
        $_SESSION['lowRange'] = $lowAge;
    }else{
        $lowAge == '18';
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['highRange'])){
    $highAge = $filter->filter($_SESSION['highRange']);
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['highRange'])){
        $highAge = $filter->filter($_POST['highRange']);
        $_SESSION['highRange'] = $highAge;
    }else{
        $highAge == '60';
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['keyword'])){
    $keyword = $filter->filter($_SESSION['keyword']);
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        $keyword = $filter->filter($_POST['keyword']);
        $_SESSION['keyword'] = $keyword;
    }
}


$query = "SELECT
        ads.ad_id,
        ads.ad_age,
        ads.ad_city,
        ads.ad_rate,
        ads.ad_keyword,
        ads.ad_approved,
        ads.ad_date,
        users.id,
        users.username

        FROM
            ads
        INNER JOIN
            users
        ON
            ads.ad_user = users.user_id 
        WHERE
            ads.ad_approved = '0'
    ";


if(isset($city) && !empty($city)){
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_city = :city";
}else{
    $city = '';
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_city != :city";
}

if(isset($rate) && !empty($rate)){
    if($rate == "all"){
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate >= 0";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate1"){
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 0 AND 150";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate2"){
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 151 AND 250";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate3"){
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 251 AND 350";
    }
    else if($rate == "rate4"){
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate BETWEEN 351 AND 5000";
    }else{
        $query .= " AND ads.ad_rate >= 0";
    }
}

if(isset($lowAge, $highAge) && !empty($lowAge) && !empty($highAge)){
    $lowAge = $lowAge;
    $highAge = $highAge;
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_age BETWEEN :lowAge AND :highAge";
}else{
    $lowAge = 18;
    $highAge = 60;
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_age BETWEEN :lowAge AND :highAge";
}
if(isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)){
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_content LIKE :keyword";
}else{
    $keyword = '';
    $query .= " AND ads.ad_content != :keyword";
}

$query .= " ORDER BY ads.ad_date DESC";
$queryPage = $query." LIMIT $starting_position, $records_per_page";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($queryPage);
$stmt->bindParam(":city", $city);
$stmt->bindParam(":lowAge", $lowAge);
$stmt->bindParam(":highAge", $highAge);
$stmt->bindParam(":keyword", $keyword);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Here is the pagination section.

```
$stmtPage = $conn->prepare($queryPage);
$stmtPage->bindParam(":city", $city);
$stmtPage->bindParam(":lowAge", $lowAge);
$stmtPage->bindParam(":highAge", $highAge);
$stmtPage->bindParam(":keyword", $keyword);
$stmtPage->execute();
$resultsPagination = $stmtPage->fetchAll();

$total_no_of_records = $stmtPage->rowCount();

if($stmtPage->rowCount() > 0){
    $current_page = 1;
    $total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);  

    if(isset($_POST["page"])){
       $current_page = $_POST["page"];
    }   

    ?><div class="row text-center"><ul class='pagination'><?php

    if($current_page != 1){
        $previous = $current_page - 1;            
        echo "<li><a class='boldTextLink paginationLinkPrev panelBGSHSM' data-prev-id='".$previous."'>PREVIOUS PAGE</a></li>";          
    }

    if($current_page < $total_no_of_pages){
        $next = $current_page + 1;
        echo "<li><a class='boldTextLink paginationLink panelBGSHSM' data-next-id='".$next."'>NEXT PAGE</a></li>";
    }
    ?></ul></div><?php
    $recordsTotal = $total_no_of_records;
}
```

Sorry for it being such a lengthy post, I figured the more code the better for someone to understand what I am trying to accomplish. Or direct me to the proper way to do this.
Thanks again for your time and patience. :)

Comment: check this link , may be help you , - and sorry i don't understand exactly what you are facing  error  ...https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-with-search-filter-php/

Comment: Please asked always exact error ! Don't post complete code.

Comment: Hi @BloodyProgrammer, I am actually breaking down that code now and seeing how I can incorporate it into my own project. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Tell me what exact error is coming , When you are click the pagination button !

Comment: The problem I have, is getting the values from the filter data to the pagination query so that when the user clicks on the next page link the filtered values are passed along to the pagination query. Right now a user can filter the data but when they click next page it wont return the required values based on the filters selected. It just resets the query to the default.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden fields and store filter values in hidden fields, and when the time of pagination you can get values from hidden fields, and pass to pagination code.

**For Example :** 
We have two hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_city" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_state" value="">
```

You have two filters city & state when the time of you selected city & state, you need to save the city value in hidden_city field, state value in hidden_state field.
 Now the hidden fields became as below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_city" value="city1">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_state" value="state1">
```

When the time of pagination call you can pass above hidden values as below.

```
 var city=$("#hidden_city").val();
 var state=$("#hidden_state").val();
```

and pass city,state to pagination.